# Incorrect data returned in SSIS when using a datetime comparison

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a simple table in sql server 2008 which lists the start and end times of certain events simplified below:

```
| StartTime                 | EndTime |
| 2016-09-05 07:17:23.447 | 2016-09-05 07:36:20.613 |<br/>
| 2016-09-02 12:49:40.103 | 2016-09-04 14:49:48.327 |<br/>
| 2016-09-02 12:13:31.833 | 2016-09-02 12:32:29.790 |<br/>
| 2016-09-02 10:48:39.513 | 2016-09-02 10:54:53.697 |<br/>
| 2016-09-01 07:19:06.153 | 2016-09-01 18:53:51.407 |<br/>
```

What I want to do is using a known StartTime extract the EndTime of the previous run

Using the above table as an example,

If I have a StartTime of 2016-09-02 12:13:31.833 I want to get back 2016-09-02 10:54:53.697 where I am using

```
select top 1 EndTime from myTable where StartTime < '2016-09-02 12:13:31.833
```

My query works perfectly every time in SQL server however I need to run it as part of an SSIS package and it doesn't return the correct answer. Instead it returns 2016-09-04 14:49:48.327

It seems that when I run my 'Execute SQL task' is SSIS, only the date part of the StartTime is being used in the comparison. The parameter for the SQl task is set up using datatype DATE (there doesn't seem to be an option for datetime!!)

Is there any way to get it to use the whole DateTime as none of the other datatypes (DB_Date,DB_Time,DB_Timestamp etc) seem to work?

Comment: 1. SELECT TOP 1 Without ORDER BY can be misleading
2. If it returns 2016-09-04 14:49:48.327 Why you think only the date part  is being used in the comparison ? It returns even bigger date....

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the result. You are requesting a *random* row as long as it is greater than a certain datetime. Either specify an order or use  `MAX(EndTime)`

Comment: That is one downside that I found out about SSRS and SSIS is the fact that there isn't a Data/Time datatype only date. You will need to change your query to account for this in some way. Because as @PanagiotisKanavos said previously the query will only return a random row since it disregards time. One thing you could do if you have access is to set up an agent job and throw the row you need into a new or temp table and then read the value you need from there. That way the SQL is ran in SQL Server and not SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the lag function to return the previous row.

```
DECLARE @MyStartTime datetime = '2016-09-02 12:13:31.833'

SELECT
    [PreviousEndTime]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [StartTime]
        ,LAG([EndTime]) OVER (ORDER BY [StartTime]) [PreviousEndTime]
    FROM [MyTable]
    ) [tbl]
WHERE [StartTime] = @MyStartTime
```